# how open a new page from autocomplete item select - primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I'm building an autocomplete which shows a list of web pages and when user select one of theses, it should open that page.
How could I do that ?

**navbar.xhtml**

```
                                 <p:autoComplete id="autoMenu"
                                             value="#{menuController.componenteP}"
                                            completeMethod="#{menuController.getAutoComplete}"
                                            converter="genericConverter"
                                            var="componente"
                                            itemLabel="#{componente.dsComponente}"
                                            itemValue="#{componente}"
                                            queryDelay="50"
                                            forceSelection="false"                                                                
                                            placeholder="Menu"
                                            required="false"                                               
                                            >
                                   <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{menuController.onItemSelect}" update="msgs"/>
                                <f:attribute name="classe" value="Componente" />
                                <p:column>
                                    <b><h:outputText value="#{componente.codigo}"/></b>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                   
                                    <p:outputLabel rendered="#{componente != null}" value="#{componente.dsComponente}" />
                                    
                                    
                                </p:column>
                            </p:autoComplete>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way :

**MenuController.java**

```
  public void onItemSelect(SelectEvent<Componente> event) {
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext extContext = ctx.getExternalContext();
    String url = extContext.encodeActionURL(ctx.getApplication().getViewHandler().getActionURL(ctx, event.getObject().getDsUrl()));
    try {
       extContext.redirect(url);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
       throw new FacesException(ioe);
    }
}
```